# Make search box with autosuggest

Tags: php, api, search-engine, bing, autosuggest

I'm trying to make a search box with the google/bing "autosuggest" functionality. Having searched the site, the closest I have found to this is here: [Custom box with autocomplete from Google/Bing. Is there any way to read the received json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209259/custom-box-with-autocomplete-from-google-bing-is-there-any-way-to-read-the-rece)

The script on the jsfiddle.net works great, however when I try to replicate the code it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#hulk").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            console.log("source");
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://api.bing.com/osjson.aspx?Query=" + encodeURIComponent(request.term) + "&JsonType=callback&JsonCallback=?",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                /*data: {
                "Query": request.term,
                "JsonType": "callback",
                "JsonCallback" : "?"
            },*/


                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("success!");
                    var suggestions = [];
                    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
                        console.log("suggestion: " + val);
                        suggestions.push(val);
                    });
                    response(suggestions);

                }
            });
        }
    });
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" id="hulk" />
 </body>
</html>
```

I am no expert when it comes to coding (mainly use php) and would appreciate any help to make this work :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this your complete code?

Comment: For now yes. I'm just trying to have an input box that uses the bing autosuggest api. Once I have this working I can then incorporate it into the more fuller site. Appreciate your help!

Comment: If this is your entire code, you have not included jquery in your code, that can be one of the reason it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js" integrity="sha256-+C0A5Ilqmu4QcSPxrlGpaZxJ04VjsRjKu+G82kl5UJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.bootstrap3.min.css" integrity="sha256-ze/OEYGcFbPRmvCnrSeKbRTtjG4vGLHXgOqsyLFTRjg=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
</head>
<body>
  <select id="select-state" placeholder="Pick a state...">
    <option value="">Select a state...</option>
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
    <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
    <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="CA">California</option>
    <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
    <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
    <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
    <option value="DC">District of Columbia</option>
    <option value="FL">Florida</option>
    <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
    <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
    <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
    <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
    <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('select').selectize({sortField: 'text'});});</script>
```